# Como popular um select com JQuery, JSON e AJAX ? (MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, mvc

Segui alguns códigos que encontrei aqui de como popular um selectbox, porém não está funcionando, será que falta alguma coisa ?  Estou pegando uma lista de dados com a minha Controller.

**JavaScript**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).select(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/Empresas/SelecionarEmpresas",
                data: { empresa: $("#empresa").val() },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (json) {
                    var options = $('#empresa');
                    options.find('option').remove();
                    $.each(json, function (key, value) {
                                 $('<option').val(value.IdEmpresa).text(value.Nome).appendTo(options);
                        //options += '<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>';
                    });   
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

**View**

```html
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Empresa: </label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <select class="form-control" name="empresa" id="empresa"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Controller**

```
public class EmpresasController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Empresas()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult SelecionarEmpresas()
        {
            EmpresaBLL bll = new EmpresaBLL();
            List lista = bll.SelecionarEmpresa();

            return Json(new { lista }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**BLL**

```
public class EmpresaBLL
    {
        public List SelecionarEmpresa()
        {
            EmpresaDAL dal = new EmpresaDAL();
            DataTable dt = dal.SelecionarEmpresa();

            List ListaDeEmpresa = new List();
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                EmpresaModel emp = new EmpresaModel
                {
                    IdEmpresa = Convert.ToInt32(dr["IDEMPRESA"]),
                    Nome = dr["NOME"].ToString(),
                    LogoPath = dr["LOGPATH"].ToString()                                
                };
                ListaDeEmpresa.Add(emp);
            }
            return ListaDeEmpresa;
        }
```

**Model**

```
public class EmpresaModel
    {
        public int IdEmpresa { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string LogoPath { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: se você fizer `console.log(json)` tem algum retorno? como é esse retorno? dentro do antes do each você remove todos options, e dentro do each vc utiliza um seletor que não existe, e possui syntax inválida

Comment: Não retornou nada... O código antes do each eu apaguei, e o de dentro eu preciso criar o seletor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consegui arrumar... Ta ai pra quem tiver a mesma dúvida que eu.

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "/Empresas/SelecionarEmpresas",
            data: { empresa: $("#empresa").val() },
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (obj) {
                if (obj != null) {
                    var data = obj.data;
                    var selectbox = $('#empresa');
                    selectbox.find('option').remove();
                    $.each(data, function (i, d) {
                        $('<option>').val(d.IdEmpresa).text(d.Nome).appendTo(selectbox);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Obrigado por compartilhar a solução meu brother, consegui fazer tambem, graças a você ... vlw, tava quebrando cabeça