# Mudar value select via ajax conforme outro select com dados estáticos

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tenho este select, onde o usuário deverá selecioná-lo:

```
<select asp-for="Configuracao.TipoEquipamento" class="form-control">
<option value="0">Catraca</option>
<option value="1">Fechadura</option>
</select>
```

Porém se ele selecionar catraca, os outros select tem que vim preenchido desta maneira:

```
 <select asp-for="Configuracao.SentidoTeclado" id="cbSentidoTeclado" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="I">Irrelevante</option>
                                        <option value="E">Entrada</option>
                                        <option value="S">Saída</option>
                                    </select>
```

Senão ele tem que vim preenchido como os seguintes campos:

```
<select asp-for="Configuracao.SentidoTeclado" id="cbSentidoTeclado" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="P">Principal</option>
                                    <option value="S">Secundária</option>
                                    <option value="D">Todos</option>
                                </select>
```

Como posso mudar isso em tempo de execução via ajax? Serão vários selects que terão que ser mudados.

Estou tentando fazer desta forma: porém toda vez que eu clico no cbTipoEquipamento, ele adiciona novamente os dados:

```
$("#cbTipoEquipamento").change(function () {
        //Pega o value da opção selecionada
        let selectedValue = $("#cbTipoEquipamento option:selected").val();

        //Depois disso, você pode fazer checar o valor do seu select e popular o outro select com as opções que você deseja.

        if (selectedValue === '0') {
            $("#cbSentidoTeclado").append($("<option />").val('I').text('Irrelevante'));
            $("#cbSentidoTeclado").append($("<option />").val('E').text('Entrada'));
            $("#cbSentidoTeclado").append($("<option />").val('S').text('Saída'));
        } else {
            $("#cbSentidoTeclado").append($("<option />").val('P').text('Principal'));
            $("#cbSentidoTeclado").append($("<option />").val('S').text('Secundária'));
            $("#cbSentidoTeclado").append($("<option />").val('D').text('Todos'));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como popular um select com JQuery, JSON e AJAX ? (MVC)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/156339/como-popular-um-select-com-jquery-json-e-ajax-mvc)

Comment: Eu preciso saber como popular dependendo do valor de outro select, e não são dados vindo do banco, são dados estáticos.

Comment: É que no título da sua pergunta está *"Mudar value select via ajax"* :)
Basta retornar uma lista de valores na chamada ajax, que seriam os dados que deseja colocar no select, e usar o lógica do exemplo acima pra colocar os dados nos options

Comment: Alterei para ficar mais claro.

Comment: Não precisa ser uma pesquisa no banco de dados, basta sua chamada ajax retornar uma lista/array com os pares de valores para os options

Comment: Seu código me parece correto, acho que está faltando só limpar os itens anteriores antes de fazer o append. Você pode fazer isso usando `empty()`, assim:  `$("#cbSentidoTeclado").empty()`

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve criar um event listener para o change do primeiro select, coloque um ID no seu select e inclua o script:

```
$("#selectId").change(function(){
    //Pega o value da opção selecionada
    let selectedValue = $("#selectIdoption:selected").val();

    //Depois disso, você pode fazer checar o valor do seu select e popular o outro select com as opções que você deseja.

    if (selectedValue === '0') {

    } else { 

    }
});
```

Acredito que você não precisa de ajax nesse caso, a menos que as opções sejam carregadas de um banco de dados ou Web Service, caso sejam, será necessário que você crie a api para carregar as opções conforme o valor do select. Caso contrário, é só popular com Javascript os selects com o seguinte código para cada opção:

```
$("#selectId").append($("<option />").val('valueDaOpcao').text('textDaOpcao'));
```

Comment: Eu tentei fazer desta forma, porém toda vez que eu clico no cbTipoEquipamento, ele adiciona novamente as mesmas opções, vou atualizar a pergunta de como estou fazendo.

Comment: Limpei antes de incluí-los e deu certo, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Já que você não vai consultar no banco, pode fazer um array no javascript só esperando para colocar combobox ao escolher a opção

```js
var catraca = 
       [
          {value: 'I', text: 'Irrelevante'},
          {value: 'E', text: 'Entrada'},
          {value: 'S', text: 'Saída'},
       ]
       
 var fechadura = 
       [
          {value: 'P', text: 'Principal'},
          {value: 'S', text: 'Secundária'},
          {value: 'D', text: 'Todos'},
       ]
       $( document ).ready(function(){
         mudar(0);
       })
       
       $('.equipamento').on('change', function(){
          var choose = $(this).val()
       //   console.log( choose )
          mudar( choose )
       })
       
       function mudar( esc ){
          var comboBox = $('#comboBox')
          var option = "";
          var local = [];
          
          if( esc == 0 ){
          //console.log('Catrada')
            local = catraca;            
          } else{
          //console.log('Fechadrua')
            local = fechadura;
          }
          //console.log( local )
          $.each( local, function(i, j){
             option += "<option value='"+j.value+"'>"+j.text+"</option>"
          } )
          
          comboBox.find('option').remove()
          comboBox.append( option )
       }
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<select asp-for="Configuracao.TipoEquipamento" class="form-control equipamento" >
  <option value="0">Catraca</option>
  <option value="1">Fechadura</option>
</select>

<select id="comboBox" class="form-control">
        
  </select>
<!--
 <select asp-for="Configuracao.SentidoTeclado" id="cbSentidoTeclado" class="form-control">
          <option value="I">Irrelevante</option>
          <option value="E">Entrada</option>
          <option value="S">Saída</option>
  </select>
Senão ele tem que vim preenchido como os seguintes campos:

<select asp-for="Configuracao.SentidoTeclado" id="cbSentidoTeclado" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="P">Principal</option>
                                    <option value="S">Secundária</option>
                                    <option value="D">Todos</option>
                                </select>
                                -->
```